# NullPointerException in Android when trying to use Getter or Setter at EditText

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, getter-setter

The following code throws a NullPointerException and I do not know why. The problem seems that I am not referencing the EditText objects correctly. But I don't know how to make it correct.

Here the interesting part of my code:

```
private static ArrayList<String> roomList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ArrayList<String> deviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private static String project_name;
    private static String router_ip;
    private static String port;
    private static String device_name;
    private static String room_name;
    private static String datatype;
    private static String grpaddr;
    private static boolean status;

    private EditText et_project_name;
    private EditText et_router_ip;
    private EditText et_port;

    private Spinner spinner_dpt; 
    private CheckBox cb_checkStatus;
    private EditText et_device_name;
    private EditText et_groupaddress;
    private View textEntryView;

    private static final String[] items={"1.001 (Lichtschalter)", "5.001 (Dimmer/Jalousien)",
          "9.001 (Temperaturanzeige)", "1.008 (Jalousien)"};

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private static ManualConfigDBAdapter dbHelper;

    /**
     * OnCreate
     * */ 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_project_manually);

        setup();
    }

    /**
     * Setup
     * */ 
    public void setup(){

        //DATABASE
        // Add project to Database
        dbHelper = new ManualConfigDBAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        // set the app icon as an action to go home
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        //enable tabs in actionbar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab.
        // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
        // Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }


        //get the controls from the layout
        et_project_name = (EditText) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.project_name);
        et_router_ip = (EditText) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.router_ip);
        et_port = (EditText) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.port);

        //Use a input filter for the input of the IP adress
        InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                if (end > start) {
                    String destTxt = dest.toString();
                    String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
                    if (!resultingTxt.matches ("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) { 
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
                        for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++) {
                            if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            return null;
            }
        };

        et_router_ip.setFilters(filters);

    }
```

And LogCat:

```
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx/de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProjectManually}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProjectManually.setup(CreateProjectManually.java:152)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProjectManually.onCreate(CreateProjectManually.java:75)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4562)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
02-16 20:09:25.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26658):    ... 11 more
02-16 20:09:25.770: D/dalvikvm(26658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 4% free 14704K/15303K, paused 2ms+3ms
```

The used xml-file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >




    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/project_save_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/project_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/project_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/project_name_hint" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/project_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/router_ip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/router_ip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:digits="0123456789."
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/router_adress_info"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|phone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/placeholder"
            android:src="@drawable/bertrandtlogoinv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/info_settings"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/placeholder"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@color/ics_blue" />

        <ImageView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/placeholder"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@color/ics_blue" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/router_ip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Port"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/port"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/port_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="5" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The following line throws the error:

```
et_router_ip.setFilters(filters);
```

**SOLUTION**

To create a 3 different fragments with view pager you should:

1)Create FragmentActivity with view pager and view pager adapter.

2)Create 3 Fragments with static instance

```
public final class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{   
    public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
        return new Fragment1();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
// your fragment xml view
        return view;
    }
}
```

3)Fill view pager adapter with it;

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter

{    
    public InstallFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {     
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Fragment1.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return Fragment2.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return Fragment3.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you point out which line throws the nullException?

Comment: just added it one second before ;-)

Comment: Helpful to tell us what's null, or at least the line.

Comment: Did you check if et_router_ip is null? If so, are you sure there is an EditText with the ID "router_ip" inside your view pager? 
Can you show us the xml you used?

Comment: I already added it to my main post the following line throws the error  `et_router_ip.setFilters(filters);` the EditText

Comment: the EditText with this ID exists, I have added my xml File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.id.router_ip` exists but it does not exist within a ViewPager element with the id of pager according to all the code you have posted. By calling findViewById() on the reference to your ViewPager you are only looking within that ViewPager object for `R.id.router_ip` and not globally within all inflated XML elements.

If the above XML file called is not called `activity_create_project_manually.xml`, then your problem extends from not having inflated the required XML into memory before using elements within it.

`setContentView()` inflates an XML file into memory. You can also do it with a LayoutInflater but I don't think this solution is for you.

Comment: The problem seems then to be not having inflated the xml into memory... How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please give me a hint? In the comments between me and zetsin are some additional information

Comment: @Mr.Mojo I added more info about inflating XML.

Comment: Now there is no more nullpointerexception now but I have the same view in all three tabs/fragments... before there were three different one.

Comment: I found the solution and have added it to my main post! Will mark this as answer because you were a good help!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

however, i cant see **paper** in **The used xml-file**.

Comment: This code was auto-generated by Eclipse as I created a new activity with tabs+swipe. What can I do now?

Comment: at de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProjectManually.setup(CreateProjectManually.java:152), u can show me the code in the 152th line.

Comment: My `activity_create_project_manually.xml` looks like this `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CreateProjektManually" />`

Comment: line 152 is this one `et_router_ip.setFilters(filters);`

Comment: debug it and step over, to check which one is the null object

Comment: seems to be a problem with the setContentView() and the ViewPager. But I cannot find the reason and/or solution

Comment: et_project_name and et_port is null too??

Comment: //try this one??
        et_project_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.project_name);
        et_router_ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.router_ip);
        et_port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);

Comment: try to delete gen folder and bin folder, then clean your project

Comment: Again same problem. There has to be a problem with my setContentView() and the ViewPager....

Comment: I thought so.. there is no more nullpointerexception now but I have the same view in all three tabs/fragments... before there were three different one..